# https rest request works in browser and postman not from soap ui

Tags: rest, google-chrome, ssl, soapui, postman

I am trying to hit a rest api, it works fine from browser and postman. But when I try from SOAP UI it throwing "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version".

I updated SoapUI-5.3.0.vmoptions with this property 
`-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.2`. Now its throwing "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure".

Could you please help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by following below options based on some other threads.

We need to remove below line from "C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\soapui.bat" and use the same to launch soap ui.

`if exist "%SOAPUI_HOME%..\jre\bin" goto SET_BUNDLED_JAVA`

once we remove that it executes below line from the bat file, it uses our system java which has solved issue.

`if exist "%JAVA_HOME%" goto SET_SYSTEM_JAVA`

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather avoid SSLv3 and activate TLSv1.1 instead : -Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

Comment: Tried that as well. It is not working. Any other suggestions please.

Comment: remove this property and try again

Comment: Ya that was the initial setup i had, without this property as i mentioned in the problem statement. any other suggestion please.